# How to put lables under each image in LaTex?

Tags: latex

I am using overleaf to write my paper. I want to put (a)(b)(c)(d) labels under each image. How can I do that?

```
\begin{figure}[ht!] %!t
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{15_6277.png}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{16_6277.png}
 \\[\smallskipamount]
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{17_6277.png}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{18_6277.png}
 \\[\smallskipamount]
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{19_6277.png}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{ensemled_6277.png}

\caption{Experiments Results and Final Ensemble Result}
\label{Compare_S}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: have a look at the subcaption package. If you need a more detailed answer, add a compilable [mre] to your question.

Comment: please also don't spam the tags with everything which has the string `tex` in it. How on Earth is a question about images related to biblatex??? Also pdflatex and xetex are contradicting (but also unrelated to the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in a `tabular` environment inside the figure;

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}% l,c,r
      \includegraphics{} & \includegraphics{}\\
      (a) & (b)\\
      \includegraphics{} & \includegraphics{}\\
      (c) & (d)\\
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{\label{fig:label}Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Better avoid `\centerline`. There is no good reason to use it.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Without it, the table aligns on the left. And the `centering` environment doesn't work there. (I'm using the `memoir` documentclass, in case that matters.)

Comment: `\centering` works fine if your images don't exceed the available text width.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Indeed it does. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: this code worked for me , Thanks :)